# Run a command in SCons without dependencies

Tags: scons

I want to run a command in SCons which doesn't have any input/output files (actually the input and output are the same file). At the moment I am just manually running it with subprocess.Popen but is there a more SConsy way of doing it?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [Command](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-user.html#chap-builders-commands) function to run whatever external command you run via Popen, and you can use the [AlwaysBuild](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.0.1/HTML/scons-user.html#AEN1356) function to ensure your command is always run even if the target file exists. Scons doesn't like dependency cycles, so leave the source list empty.

```python
myfile = env.Command('myfile.out', [], 'echo Hello world > $TARGETS')
env.AlwaysBuild(myfile)
```

The scons wiki also has a recipe for [PhonyTargets](http://www.scons.org/wiki/PhonyTargets) which makes it easy to set up a lot of simple commands.

Comment: If there is already a rule to build 'myfile.out' then it complains there are multiple ways to build the target. I want to have one rule to create the file, and another to modify it.

Comment: I think having two rules for one target is a bad idea. How does scons know whether or not the 'modify' rule has been invoked if the target exists? It will work better if you have two targets, one for each rule. Or have one rule that performs both the 'create' and 'modify' actions.

Comment: Pay attention to the scons docs where it states `AlwaysBuild` is a misleading name. There are still some rules scons evaluates before actually issuing the command.